# Twitter login issue with laravel socialite

Tags: laravel, twitter, laravel-socialite

I am using socialite package for authentication with twitter and facebook. With facebook it is working fine but with Twitter it is giving error.

[image]

I am not sure where is the issue and why it is saying "Could not authenticate you". I have set the callback for the twitter. Please if anyone facing the issue please let me know and provide me the suggesstion where i am going wrong.

Comment: Does your Twitter app have elevated access, or essential access?

Comment: Hello @AndyPiper  thanks for the reply. Can you please tell me why needed elevated access?

Comment: Hello @AndyPiper i have essential access.

Comment: I don't know how this package calls the Twitter API, but if it is calling a `/1.1/` URI path then it will need elevated access.

Comment: I'm mistaken, looking at the code this should support OAuth 2.0 so how have you configured your Twitter app in the dashboard?

Comment: Hello @AndyPiper i have access to the Oauth2.0 in the dashboard.

Comment: How have you configured the OAuth 2.0 settings? I'm not familiar with Socialite or how it expects to connect to Twitter, so it may require specific values.

Comment: With socialite you only need to pass client_id and client_secrete and redirect_url and it will returns the authenticate user information

Comment: @PranaySute were you able to figure it out ?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and solved it by **activating only OAuth 1.0a** and using the **API key/secret** provided under *Keys and Tokens -> Consumer keys* as my "Client ID and Secret".

Using the regular Client ID & Secret provided after activating OAuth 2.0 in your twitter app is just not working.

*Note that you may have to **regenerate** the consumer keys.*
[image]

[image]

Comment: To whom it may concern, this answers resolves the stated issue idk why it's not marked yet